# What are the benefits of having a remote database for your command line utility

Tags: database, api, packages

I'm current working on a command line app that will grab resources online for you when you're setting up a new project locally. Right now all the urls for the resources I need are hardcoded into the application and adding new targets require updating the software.

What are the benefits of hosting a database remotely that the application would query to get new packages. Sort of like `npm` and any other generic package manager out there. Are there any best practises in setting something like this up?

Comment: You answered your own question. `Right now all the urls for the resources I need are hardcoded into the application and adding new targets require updating the software...` -- That's why.

Comment: Where is the commandline app running?